# Chinese Idiom puzzle 11 (中文填字遊戲)

Tags: idioms, games, puzzle

[image]

1. 李白名詩: 「舉頭望明月, ?????」
2. Hate the social status quo and the state of the world
3. Grammar mistake
4. The peach blossom is the same but the missed person is nowhere to be seen
5. Go between and put things together
6. Very stable
7. Feel Congenial the first time meeting someone
8. For a just cause, not looking back
9. Always accompany each other
10. 「黃山、廬山、雁蕩山」 + 「泰山、華山、衡山、嵩山、恆山」
11. Realize the difficulty is too great and retreat
12. A lesson without using words
13. Reason
14. Lovers separate
15. Long history
16. The legend of how 宋太祖 (Song Taizu) was championed as emperor
17. Lamenting that people today have lost the loyal and honest heart of the ancients.
18. God of Wealth
19. 「學無前後」 下句
20. distract the enemy and attack where they don't expected
21. Defraud or forcefully seize
22. 「鳥之將死，其鳴也哀」 下句

A. Those who pass the imperial examination in the rural examination (first pass)

B. Determine expenses based on income

C. Improper measures or useless waste of energy and no results

D. appear and disappear unpredictablely

E. The hope is extremely ardent (similar to 望穿秋水)

F. Metaphor for 'comments are profound and pertinent or the performance is vivid'

G. It is a metaphor for the sharp opposition between the actions and words of the two sides.

H. Career advance in great speed and reach great height

I. Coincidence

J. Deep regret

K. Be the first to overwhelm others with momentum

L. Using retreat as a means to advance

M. The story of 劉関張 became sworn brothers

N. There's nothing one won't do

O. Continuous without end

P. Angry and dissatisfied

Q. 「儒、釋、道」+「帝王、文士、官吏、醫卜、僧道、士兵、農民、工匠、商賈」

R. The truth words from deepest part of one's heart.

S. Stable, unshakable like a mountain

T. The long narrative poem by 白居易 about the story of 唐玄宗 and 楊貴妃

U. Folk sayings

V. The place where 諸葛亮 died

W. The more the better

X. Sickness reached the late stage, the chance of recovery is slim

Y. Unexpectedly benefited from one's own personal disaster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tips: [博学网](https://www.boshixue.com/chengyu/) has a function called 指定位置搜索, which is very useful for the word puzzle.

> [image]

Comment: Very good.  Please see (12). 不言之教 (N). 無所不為 (O). 源源不絕. Edit them and I will accept your answer

Comment: @Tang Ho♦ Thank you. I just edited.