# Chinese Idiom puzzle 12 (中文填字遊戲)

Tags: idioms, games, puzzle

Please solve the puzzle below

[image]

1. sharp tongue (**edit:** the first character was replaced by  a Homophone)
2. A match made in heaven
3. Come back to life by borrowing a corpse (a metaphor for things that have been eliminated or fallen reappear in another form)
4. Terminal lucidity
5. 杜甫詩作: 朱門酒肉臭 ?????
6. looks legit; looks the part (Cantonese expression)
7. Vast ocean of people (implies hard to find someone in it)
8. can't wait to go home
9. A type of 對聯 (couplet)
10. Ashamed
11. hostage
12. It is dangerous at the top
13. Knowingly ask
14. Tai Chi
15. It is so obvious that no words are needed
16. Buddhist term: refers to the world of bliss
17. criminal
18. submit and become a vassal state
19. 國之將()，必有()孽
20. It will fail on its own without being attacked
21. Unproven and unfounded words
22. 9th September in Lunar calendar
23. obey
24. Without the lips, the teeth will feel cold.
25. a dead-end road

A. panicking

B. proclaim oneself a sovereign

C. In the highest official position among all ministers

D. The social status of the two families is equal

E. Ho Chi Minh City's old name

F. Convince

G. The walking dead

H. Everyone fears for himself

I. Important idea of 墨学

J. Soul

K. always together

L. The road ahead is uncertain

M. Country destroyed

N. Profit

O. Stay far away from

P. Not afraid to die

Q. Heavy casualties

R. Already knew

S. The only way

T. Time flys like an arrow

U. Nobody wants it

V. Composite photo

W. Carrying great sin

X. Youthful age (of a woman)

Y. Offend

Comment: It's a shame there's not an easier way to fill it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

01 灵牙利齿 （伶牙俐齿）
02 天作之合
03 借尸还魂
04 回光返照
05 路有冻死骨
06 似模似样
07 人海茫茫
08 归心似箭
09 无情对
10 自惭形秽
11 人质
12 位高思危（居高思危）
13 明知故问
14 太极
15 不言而喻
16 西天
17 罪犯
18 称臣纳贡
19 国之将亡，必有妖孽
20 不攻自破
21 道听途说
22 重阳
23 服从
24 唇亡齿寒
25 死路一条

a 六神无主
b 称孤道寡
c 位极人臣
d 门当户对
e 西贡
f 说服
g 行尸走肉
h 人人自危
i 非攻
J 灵魂
k 形影不离
l 前路茫茫
m 国破家亡
n 利润
o 敬而远之
p 视死如归
q 伤亡惨重
r 心知肚明
s 必经之路（必由之路）
t 光阴似箭
u 无人问津
v 合成照
w 罪孽深重
x 花样年华
y 冒犯

Comment: Good job.  I have 花樣年華 for (X). 不攻自破 for (20) but 不攻而破 is also valid; I have 冒犯 for (Y;)  although侵犯 is usually translated as  'violate' but I would accept 侵犯 as 'offend' because both 'offend'  and 'violate'  share  a sense of 'hostile action'

Comment: You are right, my chinese is rusty, 花樣年華 for "...age", 不攻自破 for "...own..." and 冒犯 appears more neutral. Thx for correcting.

Comment: BTW [Chinese Idiom puzzle 11 (中文填字遊戲)](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/42124/chinese-idiom-puzzle-11-%e4%b8%ad%e6%96%87%e5%a1%ab%e5%ad%97%e9%81%8a%e6%88%b2) has not been solved yet

Comment: Enough for me today, haha. And, am I supposed to post an image as the answer btw?

Comment: You can post an image, but just write it out as you did is fine